# Can viruses infect adipose cells?

Tags: virology

Can viruses infect adipose cells or tissue?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘store’ viruses?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site. We are also not a research service for debunking vague nonsense from fiction. Please [edit] your question to: 1) be clear, focused, and specific; and 2) tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: basically can virus get into a fat cell?

Comment: *long story short*- a longer story would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Research demonstrated](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5876154/#!po=53.0303) that viruses including HIV virus can find sanctuary in adipose tissue cells.
[Earlier studies](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1043466601909998?via%3Dihub) showed that interactions between immune cells and adipocytes, specifically perinodal adipocytes, promote immune activation and adipose inflammation,suggesting adipocyte regulation of HIV replication and pathogenesis.
Adipose tissue is categorized as mainly subcutaneous or visceral depots, with other minor depots uniquely associated with critical tissues and organs such as lymph nodes (perinodal fat) and the heart (pericardial and epicardial fat). Adipose tissue contains mature adipocytes and stromal-vascular-fraction cells (AT-SVF cells) which includes preadipocytes, mesenchymal stem cells, and immune cells, and this cellular composition changes significantly during disease and metabolic disorders, most notably obesity.
Murine models demonstrated migration of immune cells into adipose tissue to become major regulators of adipocyte function and metabolism, and studies of healthy and diseased humans further showed significant accumulation of immune cells. Additionally, virion-free circulating HIV proteins such as vpr, nef, and tat [were shown](https://www.nature.com/articles/0803366) to mediate detrimental effects on adipose tissue health and systemic metabolism.

So yes, the viruses can "live" and "reside" inside adipose tissue and regulate that environment to their own benefit.